# Structure of SQL query using NOT IN / NOT EXISTS(?) with three tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-tables

I need help to figure out the right structure of query to

> find the names of those clients, who stopped in exactly the same
>   hotels as John Doe.

I have tables :

> **Clients**(clientID,  clientName)
>
> **ClientTour**(clientID, tourID)
>
> **Tours**(tourID,  country,  hotel)

It all should be written down as one query.

I'm quite new to SQL and can't write down right subqueries for it, as it uses three tables... I somewhat understand how to write similar queries for two tables, but when I tried to write this one... well, I got lost. =/

As far as I understand, I have to find the names of those clients, 
who stopped in

[All Hotels where John Doe stopped] - [Hotels where only John Doe stopped]

but who never stopped in those

[Hotels where John Doe never stopped].

Is it logically right? If it is, then I get the part that is

> SELECT c1.clientName
>
> FROM Clients c1
>
> WHERE c1.clientID NOT IN (*clientIDs of clients in [Hotels where John
>   Doe never stopped]*)
>
> AND c1.clientID IN (*clientIDs of clients in [[All Hotels where John
>   Doe stopped] - [Hotels where only John Doe stopped]]*)

but can't figure out the parts marked in Italics... how do I find clients who stopped in hotels where John Doe did/didn't stop, or the hotels where only John Doe stopped?

Also, is there any easier way to write this query down?

Comment: That's actually a pretty tricky problem for someone new to SQL !

Comment: Is *hotel* uniquely determined by *tourID*, or can the same *hotel* be listed in multiple records of *Tours*?

Comment: @trincot , it is not specified if _hotel_ is uniquely determined by _tourID_ . I suppose it can be listed multiple times.

Comment: It is possible, that the same _hotel_ value can be used for different _tourID_-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
1. Added to the outer SELECT a GROUP BY clause, replacing the need for DISTINCT, and adding the option of **countnig** hotels for each client **in the result set**. Note the result set has only hotels that 'John Doe' has attended.
2. Added a SELECT statement to count number of hotels 'John Doe' has visited at.
3. Added a HAVING clause to eliminate from the result set clients with different numbers of hotels than 'John Doe'.

```
SELECT C.clientName 
FROM (Clients AS C INNER JOIN ClientTour AS CT ON C.clientID = CT.clientID) INNER JOIN Tours AS T ON CT.tourID = T.tourID
WHERE C.clientName <> 'John Doe' 
    AND T.hotel IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.hotel
    FROM (Clients AS C1 INNER JOIN ClientTour AS CT1 ON C1.clientID = CT1.clientID) INNER JOIN Tours AS T1 ON CT1.tourID = T1.tourID
    WHERE C1.clientName = 'John Doe' 
)
GROUP BY C.clientName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINKT T.hotel) = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.hotel)
    FROM (Clients AS C2 INNER JOIN ClientTour AS CT2 ON C2.clientID = CT2.clientID) INNER JOIN Tours AS T2 ON CT2.tourID = T2.tourID
    WHERE C2.clientName = 'John Doe'
```

---

First atempt:

```
SELECT C.clientName 
FROM (Clients AS C INNER JOIN ClientTour AS CT ON C.clientID = CT.clientID) INNER JOIN Tours AS T ON CT.tourID = T.tourID
WHERE Trim(C.clientName) <> 'John Doe' 
    AND T.hotel IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.hotel
    FROM (Clients AS C1 INNER JOIN ClientTour AS CT1 ON C1.clientID = CT1.clientID) INNER JOIN Tours AS T1 ON CT1.tourID = T1.tourID
    WHERE Trim(C1.clientName) = 'John Doe' 
)
```

Comment: can I use just _C.clientName_ instead of _Trim(C.clientName)_ if there are no spaces before or after _clientName_ value? Also, I think it's a good idea to add DISTINCT after the first SELECT to avoid getting duplicates of the names...

Comment: it finds the clients who stopped in the same hotels as John Doe, but not _exactly_ . It shouldn't show the clients, who also stopped in the hotels where John Doe didn't. The query you wrote above does.

Comment: For example, John Doe stopped in hotels 'Edem', 'Plaza', 'Royal'; Eva Smith stopped in 'Plaza', 'Golden'; Adam Evans stopped in 'Plaza', 'Royal'. It shouldn't show Eva Smith, only Adam Evans.

Comment: So, how do I remove those clients, who also stopped in some other hotels?

Comment: @0lesya, I have edited the answer, hope it works (I don't have a DB to test...)